# Spring Boot: Mapper not being initialized

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm building a Java app with Spring boot, and everything was good until I tried to implement Mappers...

Apparently the mappers are not being initialized. I'm trying to implement this for the first time so I'm not sure if I'm missing something or where the issue is.

This is the issue I get when trying `mvn spring-boot:run`

```
Compilation failure: 
[ERROR] /service/impl/ProductServiceImpl.java:[33,23] variable productMapper not initialized in the default constructor
```

The ProductMapper class is:

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface ProductMapper {

    @Mapping(target = "id", source = "product.id")
    @Mapping(target = "name", source = "product.name")
    @Mapping(target = "image", source = "product.image")
    ProductDTO toProductResponse(Product product);

    default List<ProductDTO> toProductDTOList(List<Product> productList) {
        if (productList == null || productList.isEmpty()) return emptyList();
        return productList.stream().map(this::toProductResponse).collect(toList());
    }
}
```

So as far as I read in the documentation, I'm using the `@Mapper` annotation and defining a `default` method.

But when I tried to use that in a service class like the following:

```
@Service
@FieldDefaults(makeFinal = true, level = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
public class ProductServiceImpl implements ProductService {

    ProductMapper productMapper;

@Override
    public List<ProductDTO> get(String name, int page, int quantity){
        Page<Product> products = null;
        if(name.length() > 0) {
            Product item = new Product();
            item.setName("%" + name + "%");

            products = this.productRepository.findAll(Example.of(item), PageRequest.of(page-1, quantity, Sort.by("name")));
        } else {
            products = this.productRepository.findAll(PageRequest.of(page-1, quantity, Sort.by("name")));
        }

        return productMapper.toProductDTOList(products.toList());
    }

}
```

Also in my pom.xml I have the following plugins:

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>pre-integration-test</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>start</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>post-integration-test</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>stop</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*Int.java</include>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                            <goal>verify</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Could you please point me where the issue is?

Comment: The error message is quite specific and doesn't have anything to do with MapStruct; it's about your service implementation, where you aren't initializing your field. Since you're using Lombok, try `@AllArgsConstructor` (and make the field final, just as a general good practice).

Comment: Please check the same class in target directory.  Check there if you have this: private final ProductMapper productMapper; and generated constructor really initializes this field.

But first try @RequiredArgsConstructor

Comment: @chrylis-onstrike- you were right.. The issue was that I missed the ´@AllArgsConstructor´ that fix the issue. Thanks!